# Jest toHaveBeenCalled is not working when it should

Tags: angular, jestjs

So here's my case, I am writing unit test for this method using Angular:

```
sendNotification() {
    this.validateTitle();
    this.validateDescription();

    if (!this.titleValid && !this.descriptionValid) {
      this.confirmPopup();
    } else {
      this.openAlert(false, 'sent');
    }
}
```

I already Covered else part but I can't cover if path when it calls the confirmPopup method.

Here's my Jest code:

```
it('should call confirmPopup if titleValid and descriptionValid are true', () => {                         
 const confirmPopupSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'confirmPopup');                                                 
 component.titleValid = false;                                                          
 component.descriptionValid = false;                                                                       
 component.sendNotification();                                                     
 expect(confirmPopupSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Seems logically correct, did you try to debug with a breakpoint in this method running the test in debug mode?

It's hard to tell without knowing what validateTitle and validateDescription do. Maybe these mutate your booleans before you read them.

I have some minor code review suggestions:

titleValid and descriptionValid are obviously booleans, so these should start with "is" in this case: isTitleValid and isDescriptionValid.

Also I wonder whether this is correct - shouldn't the if reach the true branch when either name or description is invalid? Out of my experience it is easier to grasp, when the "happy path" comes first. So I'd assume both to be valid first and else do other stuff.

Comment: Thing was that when I called component.sendNotification() it called validateTiTle() and validateDescription() in that method and that was messing up

Comment: Then I fixed that

Comment: Ok, so my guess was lucky ;) Congratulations.